# GapDebug: Where can I get the latest version?

Tags: cordova, gapdebug

Genuitec announced the end of life for GapDebug so they don't host any installation files anymore.

I would like to download the latest version 2.4.0 but I can't find a hoster.

Comment: https://gosecure.cloud.genuitec.com/dl/package/8349-wvw-3859/installers/GapDebug-2016-update-2.4.0-offline-installer-windows.exe