# How can I automatically reconnect Chrome DevTools after reinstall a cordova app?

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome-devtools

I'm developing a hybrid Android app with `Cordova` and using `Chrome DevTools` (`chrome://inspect/#devices`) to inspect and debug.

Every time I run `cordova run android --emulator` to update the app on emulator, `DevTools` gets disconnected.

My question is how can I **automatically** reconnect `DevTools` after `Cordova` successfully launch the app?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7hz3xy/stetho_anyone_know_of_a_convenient_way_to/

Answer (score 4):

As I was not able to found anything about reconnect, I was only able to automate the following process:

1. close the disconnected `DevTools` window
2. open a new `DevTools` window after deploy the new app version on emulator

To **step 1** I'm using the [wmctrl](http://tripie.sweb.cz/utils/wmctrl/). I created the script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 wmctrl -c 'Developer Tools - file' || exit 0
```

and added it as a `hook` in my `config.xml`

```
<hook src="scripts/close_devtools.sh" type="before_deploy" />
```

To **step 2** I run the code below on `chrome://inspect/#devices` tab's console

```
var targetNode = document.querySelector('#device\\:emulator-5554 .browsers')

var callback = function(mutationsList) {
  for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
      document.querySelector('#device\\:emulator-5554 .action').click();
    }
  }
};

var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, {childList: true});
```

Comment: I wanted to close the current DevTools window without the use of `hook`s and `wmctrl`, so I just switch to the DevTools window and send a close command via `osascript `.
`open -a 'Google Chrome' && osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "w" using {command down}' && cordova emulate` [..]
This only works in a speciffic scenario [no other Chrome windows open, just the current DevTools, as it could misfire and close another window]

Comment: On chromium it clicks the first action that matches the query, which is "trace", not "inspect".  So I had to change the inner part to: `document.querySelectorAll('#device\\:ZY224JLXFG .action').forEach((action)=>            {if(action.innerText == "inspect") action.click();})`

Answer (score 1):

Based on Paul's answer, I updated his script and modified to my approach if an Android device is connected.

Considering the Android device is connected on local IP `192.168.0.149` on port `5037`, entering this script in `chrome://inspect/#devices` worked like a charm:

```js
const targetNode = document.querySelector('#device\\:192\\.168\\.0\\.149\\:5037 .browsers')

const callback = function(mutationsList) {
  for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
      targetNode.querySelector('.action').click();
    }
  }
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, {childList: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at gapDebug.

Its basically a wrapper around chrome devtools. If you do `cordova run android --device --debug`, gapDebug will notice the app launch and allows you to debug just like in chrome, along with some extra benefits like a screen preview.

Although it is [not supported anymore](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug-end-of-life-notice/), you can still [download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758836/gapdebug-where-can-i-get-the-latest-version) it.